Dev Containers作成時「開発コンテナーでフォルダを開く」→フォルダの選択→「開発コンテナー構成ファイルの追加」→Node.jsを選択・・と選択肢を選んでいくと、「テンプレートの適用に失敗しました」と出る
実現したいこと
「実装で学ぶフルスタックWeb開発」という書籍のp80~83あたりにある通りにdevcontainersの構築したい。
現状：
以下のエラーが出て3週間ほどそのページから全く進まず悩んでいます。
具体的な状態：
Cursorのコマンドパレットより
「開発コンテナーでフォルダを開く」→フォルダの選択→「開発コンテナー　構成ファイルの追加」→Node.jsを選択→「機能の選択」なし→と選択肢を選んでいくと、
以下スクショの通りに最後に
「テンプレートの適用に失敗しました。」＝「 Application of template faile」（英語表記の場合）
と出ます。
こればっかりが3週間ずっと出て、書籍が全く先に進まないのでこの現象を回避したいです。
環境
Windows 11
エディタ：Cursor 0.40.3
拡張機能：Dev Containersインストール済み
Docker　4.32.0
実現するために自分が試した内容とその結果
まずエラーの問題とは別に、もともと書籍ではVSCで説明されているのですが、私はCursorメインで使用していたため、
VSCodeの code . の代わりになるCursor独自の代替手段をさがしたところ
下記サイトに情報があり、その通りに設定を色々変え、 cursor . に置き換えて起動できるようにできました。
参考にしたもの：
質問スレッド
Bug: Cursor is not launching through cusrsor . or code . command in WSL2 Distro ubuntu. #870
https://github.com/getcursor/cursor/issues/870
（上記スレッドをまとめてくれたもの）
Command Cursor Editor on Linux
https://github.com/angga7togk/command-cursor-editor-linux
まずこれで cursor . に置き換えることができました。
次に前述したように問題個所の件ですが、
Cursorのコマンドパレットより
「開発コンテナーでフォルダを開く」→フォルダの選択→「開発コンテナー　構成ファイルの追加」→Node.jsを選択→「機能の選択」は何も選ばず→と選択肢を選んでいくと、
以下スクショの通りに最後に
「テンプレートの適用に失敗しました。」＝「 Application of template faile」（英語表記の場合）
と出ます。
こればっかりが3週間ずっと出て、書籍が全く先に進まないのでこの現象を回避したいです。
その後、調べた内容や資料
上記の
「テンプレートの適用に失敗しました。」＝「 Application of template faile」（英語表記の場合）
に関する情報が下記URLに唯一ありましたが、回答もないまま時間経過しクローズドしてしまっているので参考にできず。
このままでは自分で解決できないと思い、思い切って、ここで質問させてもらいました。
[dev containers] Application of template failed #9975
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/9975
原因だと思われそうな箇所
自分が調べた限りではわかりません。
対処法があれば教えてください。
よろしくお願いいたします。
◆追記
補足アドバイス有難うございます。
とりあえず、以下のログを出力してみました。
[9280 ms] Dev Containers 0.327.0 in VS Code 1.91.1 (2804893a83ef162ae6c48e8254717e25c7c7c510).
[9279 ms] Start: Run: wsl -d ubuntu -e /bin/sh -c cd '/' && /bin/sh
[9329 ms] Start: Run in host: id -un
[9650 ms] test
[9650 ms] 
[9650 ms] Start: Run in host:  (command -v getent >/dev/null 2>&1 && getent passwd 'test' || grep -E '^test|^[^:]*:[^:]*:test:' /etc/passwd || true)
[9658 ms] Start: Run in host: echo ~
[9659 ms] /home/test
[9659 ms] 
[9660 ms] Start: Run in host: test -x '/home/test/.vscode-remote-containers/bin/2804893a83ef162ae6c48e8254717e25c7c7c510/node'
[9664 ms] 
[9664 ms] 
[9664 ms] Exit code 1
[9665 ms] Start: Run in host: test -x '/home/test/.cursor-server/bin/2804893a83ef162ae6c48e8254717e25c7c7c510/node'
[9666 ms] 
[9666 ms] 
[9666 ms] Start: Run in host: test -f '/home/test/.cursor-server/bin/2804893a83ef162ae6c48e8254717e25c7c7c510/node_modules/node-pty/package.json'
[9668 ms] 
[9668 ms] 
[9668 ms] Start: Run in host: test -f '/home/test/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/vscode-remote-containers-server-0.327.0.js'
[9670 ms] 
[9670 ms] 
[9671 ms] userEnvProbe: loginInteractiveShell (default)
[9671 ms] userEnvProbe: not found in cache
[9671 ms] userEnvProbe shell: /bin/bash
[9859 ms] userEnvProbe PATHs:
Probe:     '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/mnt/c/Program Files/dotnet/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Graphviz/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/Docker/host/bin:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windowssystem32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Users/ユーザー名/AppData/Local/UniGetUI/Chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/Users/ユーザー名/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/Scripts/:/mnt/c/Users/ユーザー名/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/:/mnt/c/Users/ユーザー名/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Launcher/:/mnt/c/Users/ユーザー名/AppData/Local/Programs/WingetUI/choco-cli/bin:/mnt/c/Users/ユーザー名/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/ユーザー名/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/ユーザー名/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312:/mnt/c/Program Files/Graphviz/bin:/snap/bin'
Container: None
[10191 ms] Start: Run in Host: docker version --format {{.Server.APIVersion}}
[10420 ms] 1.46
[15157 ms] Start: Run: wsl -d ubuntu -e /bin/sh -c cd '/home/test' && /bin/sh
[15197 ms] Start: Run in host: id -un
[15465 ms] test
[15465 ms] 
[15465 ms] Start: Run in host:  (command -v getent >/dev/null 2>&1 && getent passwd 'test' || grep -E '^test|^[^:]*:[^:]*:test:' /etc/passwd || true)
[15469 ms] Start: Run in host: echo ~
[15470 ms] /home/test
[15470 ms] 
[15470 ms] Start: Run in host: test -x '/home/test/.vscode-remote-containers/bin/2804893a83ef162ae6c48e8254717e25c7c7c510/node'
[15471 ms] 
[15471 ms] 
[15471 ms] Exit code 1
[15472 ms] Start: Run in host: test -x '/home/test/.cursor-server/bin/2804893a83ef162ae6c48e8254717e25c7c7c510/node'
[15473 ms] 
[15473 ms] 
[15473 ms] Start: Run in host: test -f '/home/test/.cursor-server/bin/2804893a83ef162ae6c48e8254717e25c7c7c510/node_modules/node-pty/package.json'
[15474 ms] 
[15474 ms] 
[15474 ms] Start: Run in host: test -f '/home/test/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/vscode-remote-containers-server-0.327.0.js'
[15475 ms] 
[15475 ms] 
[15476 ms] userEnvProbe: loginInteractiveShell (default)
[15476 ms] userEnvProbe: not found in cache
[15476 ms] userEnvProbe shell: /bin/bash
[15589 ms] userEnvProbe PATHs:
Probe:     '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/mnt/c/Program Files/dotnet/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Graphviz/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/Docker/host/bin:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windowssystem32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Users/ユーザー名/AppData/Local/UniGetUI/Chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/Users/ユーザー名/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/Scripts/:/mnt/c/Users/ユーザー名/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/:/mnt/c/Users/ユーザー名/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Launcher/:/mnt/c/Users/ユーザー名/AppData/Local/Programs/WingetUI/choco-cli/bin:/mnt/c/Users/ユーザー名/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/ユーザー名/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/ユーザー名/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312:/mnt/c/Program Files/Graphviz/bin:/snap/bin'
Container: None
[33549 ms] Start: Run: C:\Users\ユーザー名\AppData\Local\Programs\cursor\Cursor.exe c:\Users\ユーザー名\.cursor\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.327.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js templates apply --workspace-folder C:\Users\ユーザー名\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-output-dir-1725456581585 --template-id ghcr.io/csutter/devcontainer-templates/barebones-nodejs:latest --template-args {"imageVariant":"20"} --features [] --tmp-dir C:\Users\ユーザー名\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-dir-1725456581585
[33824 ms] node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1058
[33825 ms]   throw err;
[33825 ms]   ^
[33825 ms] Error: Cannot find module 'c:\Users\ユーザー名\.cursor\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.327.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js'
[33825 ms]     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1055:15)
[33825 ms]     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:908:27)
[33825 ms]     at c._load (node:electron/js2c/node_init:2:13672)
[33826 ms]     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:96:12)
[33826 ms]     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
[33826 ms]   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
[33826 ms]   requireStack: []
[33827 ms] }
[33827 ms] Node.js v20.9.0
[33862 ms] Exit code 1


考えたこと：
上のログ後半にある以下にコピペしたあたりが、その原因なのかな　と推測してみました。
「Error: Cannot find module」でググってみたところ、Node.jsのエラーなのかなーとなんとなく思いつつ、
一方で検索結果がたくさん出てきすぎて、対処方法がどれなのかまでは特定できず、何したらいいか分からない感じです。
もう少し考えてみます・・・
以下、上のログの怪しい部分の抜粋です。
[33825 ms]   throw err;
[33825 ms]   ^
[33825 ms] Error: Cannot find module 'c:\Users\ユーザー名\.cursor\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.327.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js'
[33825 ms]     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1055:15)
[33825 ms]     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:908:27)
[33825 ms]     at c._load (node:electron/js2c/node_init:2:13672)
[33826 ms]     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:96:12)
[33826 ms]     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
[33826 ms]   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',



まずは、添付画像のダイアログにある「ログの表示」をクリックして何が出力されているかを確認してください（やっていないなら）。処理内でやろうとしていることや失敗したタイミング、原因などが載っていることが多いです。
自分でログの確認をしても解決が難しそうであれば、質問を編集してログを貼り付けてみてください。

アドバイス有難うございます。ログの表示を追記しました。

ひとまず書籍の内容通り、VSCode で試して問題無いことを確認してみてはどうでしょうか？何か手順が漏れているのか、VSCode と Cursor の互換性の問題なのかが現時点だとわからない気がします。

アドバイス有難うございます。確かにVSCodeとCursorの問題な可能性もありますよね。プログラミング初心者なもので、ローカルと同じようにDev Containers環境下でもCursorのサブスクのチャット機能と相談しながらプログラミングできたら便利だなーと考えて調べて苦労して弄ったので、もう少しだけエラーコードで粘ってみたいと思います。ダメそうだったら、後日、一度ご指摘のようにVSCodeに戻して試してみたいと思います。
